# Error: Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" (ionic 2 and firebase)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

```
saveDetails(){
  this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
    this.af.object('request/${auth.uid}').set(this.request)
    .then();
  })
```

After executing this method, an error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "request/${auth.uid}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" is being shown. Tried removing $ but that doesn't work. Pretty sure i am not passing in empty strings too.

Comment: If you are going to use string interpolation, you need to use back ticks (`) and not single quotes (') to wrap a string.

Comment: My goodness THANKS ALOT!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are going to use string interpolation, you need to use back ticks (`), and not single quotes ('), to wrap a string. See below.

```
saveDetails(){
  this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
    this.af.object(`request/${auth.uid}`).set(this.request)
    .then();
  })
```

Easy one to forget! :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use your variable in this context is this

```
saveDetails(){
  this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
    this.af.object('request/'+ auth.uid).set(this.request)
    .then();
  })
```

Comment: this answer is another nice option. Instead of using the wrong quotes all the time it's cleaner to stick with + concatenation